# Delete folders with FTP

Tags: permissions, ftp

I have client who is the owner of a printer shop. I have configured for him an FTP Server where clients can drop him big files they want to print.

I have created several FTP users. He has some premium clients and some regular clients. Regular clients are told to use the FTP user *clients*. The owner has a folder called clients with the next permisions.

```
printshopowner# ls -la
drwx-----x 9 printshopowner printshopowner   4096 Aug 17 08:07 .
drwx-wx-wx 9 printshopowner clients          4096 Jan 19 10:24 clients
drwxrwx--- 2 premiumuser    printshopowner 4096 Jan 19 08:13 premiumuser
```

It is working fine. A Client can upload files without seeing other clients' files. Problem is when a client uploads a folder. The FTP user *printshopowner*  can not delete these folders.

```
[printshopowner/clients]# ls -la
drwx-wx-wx 9 printshopowner clientes         4096 Jan 19 10:24 .
drwx-----x 9 printshopowner printshopowner   4096 Aug 17 08:07 ..
drwxr-xr-x 3 clients        clients          4096 Dec  3 11:57 folderA
```

Any idea how should I configured the FTP dropbox to achieve the desired functionality?

Comment: Which FTP Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try setting local_umask in vsftpd.conf

local_umask = 0002

Also consider looking into file_open_mode. This controls the permissions with which uploaded files are created with umasks being applied on top of this value.

Answer (score 1):

To delete (or to say it properly "unlink") file/directory X, a user does not need to have ownership of X, or neither write permission on X, but they have to have write permission on the **X's parent** directory.

In your case, printshopowner can delete (rmdir) folderA, but only if it is empty. User printshopowner cannot delete anything inside folderA (no write permission for him there). If you change clients' umask to 002, he will make folderA as "drwxrwxr-x" and printshopowner will be able to delete it (I assume printshopowner is assigned to both groups printshopowner and clients). No idea how to change umask in your FTP server.

Comment: My FTP Server is a Linux server

Comment: I have tried to set umask in .bashrc with umask 002 without success. Any idea?

Comment: Without knowing your FTP server, you probably need to set the umask in the ftpd.conf (or something close to) and cycle the FTP daemon to pick up the change.

Comment: My FTP server is vsftpd